# Как правильно делать разметку XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, разметка

Не могу разобраться с разметкой. Как ее сделать не применяя фиксированные значения(Чтобы она адаптировалась под размер экрана)

Моя разметка:

```
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Но все работает через одно место

Хочу получить разметку такого вида:[image: скрин]

В 1 находится `ListView`
В 2 картинка
В 3 кнопки

`ListView`

```
 <ListView

            Grid.RowSpan="2"                
            Margin="0,37,0,0" 
            SelectionMode="Single"
            x:Name="ListOfFilters" 
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}"
            Visibility="{Binding IsListOfFiltersVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    </ListView>
```

`Image`

```
    <Image Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="1" 
           x:Name="OriginalImg"
           Source="{Binding OriginalPicture}"
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
           Visibility="{Binding IsOriginalImgVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Кнопки

```
 <Button Grid.Row="2"
            Content="Open"
            x:Name="OpenImg" 
            Margin="22,23,0,15"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            Command="{Binding PickCommand}"/>
```

Все кнопки имею одинаковый `Margin` за исключением отступа слева( каждая следующая кнопка имеет больший отступ)

Проблемы с которыми я столкнулся:

Если в `ListView` много элементов(Не помещаются в экран вертикально), то он вытесняет за экран 3 и непонятно куда вытесняет 2

Из-за разных ширины элементов в `ListView`(2 листа на странице) грид будет прыгать, можно ли как-то указать(может в процентах) чтобы грид не был минимального размера по ширине и всегда максимального по высоте(Даже ели в листе будет 1 элемент)

Comment: @Smile по первой проблеме Ваш изначальный код вполне работает, только вы запутались с размещением и слиянием. При такой конструкции все должно быть нормально: `<ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" ... />`, `<Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" .../>`, `<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" .../>`

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44721/discussion-on-question-by-smile-----xaml).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы немного запутались в том, где размещать элементы и как их помещать в более чем одну ячейку. Допустим, у нас есть такая простая сетка `Grid`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Дело в том, что `RowSpan` распространяется от текущего размещения элемента вниз, а `ColumnSpan` от текущего размещения элемента вправо. Поскольку кнопка у Вас размещается в ячейках `{1,0}` и захватывает `{1,1}`, то разместить вы ее должны в `{1,0}` и задать объединение с правой ячейкой через `Grid.ColumnSpan="2"`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом случае все будет находится на своих местах.

Для решения второй проблемы используйте вместо автоматического размера относительный, как подсказал @Mirdin в своем ответе. К тому же надо убрать у `ListView` атрибут `HorizontalAlignment="Left"`, что бы он занял весь этот относительный объем изначально и больше не прыгал.

Итоговый код со всеми изменениями.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <ListView
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Margin="0,37,0,0" 
        SelectionMode="Single"
        x:Name="ListOfFilters" 
        IsItemClickEnabled="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Filters}"
        Visibility="{Binding IsListOfFiltersVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
    </ListView>

    <Image 
       Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.Column="1"
       x:Name="OriginalImg"
       Source="{Binding OriginalPicture}"
       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
       Visibility="{Binding IsListOfFiltersVisible, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Content="Open"
        x:Name="OpenImg" 
        Margin="22,23,0,15"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Command="{Binding PickCommand}"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: Ого, получилось немного больше, чем было в комментарии )

Comment: @NickVolynkin ну если уж писать ответ, так писать полностью)

Answer (score 2):

Задайте относительные размеры, а не автоматические:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="1*" MaxWidth = "60"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Тогда:

```
строки:  1 - 75%, 2 - 25% (Но не больше 60 пикселей)
столбцы: 1 - 25%, 2 - 75%
```

`MinWidth`, `MinHeight` - к сожалению могут быть заданы только в [абсолютных (фиксированых) числах](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.rowdefinition.minheight(v=vs.110).aspx)

**P.S.**

Для WPF

```
<ListView
     ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"   
</ListView>



<Button Grid.Row    = "1"
        Grid.Column = "1"/>
```

Для UWP

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ListView />
</ScrollViewer>

<Button Grid.Row    = "1"
        Grid.Column = "1"/>
```

NB! Нумерация начинается с нуля, все остальные свойства ваши. И да, не суйте в одну ячейку несколько элементов, лучше положите туда контейнер, а уже в него несколько кнопок, списков и т. д. (подойдет Grid, StackPanel...)

Comment: Воспользовался Вашим советом. Теперь если в 1 длинный List то он налазит на кнопки (3) и на них невозможно нажать UPD при открытии любого списка на кнопки нельзя нажать, даже если список короткий

Comment: @SmiLe, скорее всего потому что у вас указано `<ListView Grid.RowSpan="2"`/>, таким образом у вас он размещается в ячейках {0,0} и {0,1} и перекрывает кнопки. Надо либо убрать это свойство, либо указать кнопкам место размещения `Grid.Column = 1`